# JS function doesn't works

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm programming at the moment a very simple Log-In. I want to make a function, that checks if **char** is the same as **"V7Z'13Px8DtyJp0n'JD;"**. So far I've done this:

```
function check(char) {

    If(char == "V7Z'13Px8DtyJp0n'JD;") {

        alert("right");

    }

}
```

But my Editor(Visual Studio Code) and my Browser(Google Chrome) thinks the last *}* is wrong.
Please Help Me.

P.S. Sorry for my Englisch ._.

Comment: "If" make the "I" lowercase `if(char == "V7Z'13Px8DtyJp0n'JD;")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to replace If with if

```
function check(char) {

    if(char == "V7Z'13Px8DtyJp0n'JD;") {

        alert("right");

    }
}
```

:)

Comment: Thank you! You helped me so much!

Answer (score 1):

I see that your if statement uses a capital 'I'. If you use `if` it should do the job.

```
function check(char) {

    if(char == "V7Z'13Px8DtyJp0n'JD;") {

        alert("right");

    }   
}
```

Comment: Questions caused by typographical errors [are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. Please don't answer those.

Answer (score 1):

As other users pointed out, you have a syntax error with the if statement.

It should look like this:

```
function check(char) {
    if(char === "V7Z'13Px8DtyJp0n'JD;") { // Code changed here
        alert("right");
    }
}
```

Having said that, that syntax error is least of your problems. Any IDE nowadays should give you a warning about the simple syntax error. Simply search for JavaScript editor and use one. It will help you a lot.

Another thing worth mentioning here is the comparison operator inside your if statement. Long story short, you should always try to use triple equals '===' rather than '=='. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#:~:targetText=triple%20equals%20(%20%3D%3D%3D%20)%20will%20do,types%20differ%2C%20false%20is%20returned.). Also, for easier understanding, you can read it [here](https://bytearcher.com/articles/equality-comparison-operator-javascript/) (same topic)

Comment: I think we could handle this by our own.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on "If" -> "if":

```
function check(char) {

  if(char == "V7Z'13Px8DtyJp0n'JD;") {

    alert("right");

  }
}
```

Comment: Questions caused by typographical errors [are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow. Please don't answer those.

Comment: @Ivar is there any Faq or terms and conditions about answering these questions? I don't think, it is justified to punisch us on somebody elses mistakes.

Comment: @Ivar It is not friendly to downvote answer, simply because of your opinion. My answer not just corrects the code, but gives several advice as well, which are beneficial.

Comment: The goal of Stack Overflow is to build a repository of Q&A's that help future visitors, not just OP. Questions like this one only clutter up the search results for those looking for a specific solutions. That is why those are off-topic. Answering them prevents OP from deleting the question themselves. In that case it requires 3 users with 20k+ rep to delete it, which is a waste of resources.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. Who said that I downvoted anything? Also it's not an opinion, it's a decision that is made to reach the goal Stack Overflow is aiming for. The advice is good, but that is not what SO is for.